# tunnel manager could not be created in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ssh, workbench

I've been playing around with mysql workbench for almost a week now after my kids go to sleep.. spending hours trying to get this to work with the help of google, but I'm really stuck. at first, i had paramiko and pycrypto issues, but i uninstalled and then reinstalled thru terminal.  but i'm still getting the "Failed to connect to mysql at ip:port with user root  Cannot start SSH tunnel manager.   When I check the log file, I see this: 
`21:12:42 [INF][     SSH tunnel]: Starting tunnel
21:12:42 [ERR][         python]: Error running file.
21:12:42 [WRN][               ]: Tunnel manager could not be executed`

I can access mysql thru terminal without issue.  I also remember starting up SSH via terminal without issue too, but can't remember what steps I used (due to my countless google searches).  Either way, I've never had it work thru workbench.  Please help.  btw, mysql and workbench are on my local machine.